# Как сделать так чтобы виндовс не запускалась по дефолту?

Tags: linux, windows, bios, uefi

у меня стоит 2 операционки виндовс и линукс на одном жестком диске. По дефолту всегда запускается виндовс. Как сделать так чтобы при запуске компуктера всегда был выбор какую ос запустить?

Comment: Установить и настроить GRUB

Comment: Вроде бы в настройках BIOS должна быть настройка приоритета, какой загрузчик должен быть первым. Хотя GRUB тоже вариант

Answer (score 1):

Для Windows 7 и Windows XP:

Нажимаем правой кнопкой мыши на "*Мой компьютер*" -> выбираем "*Свойства*" -> переходим на вкладку "*Дополнительно*" -> в разделе "*Загрузка и восстановление*" нажимаем параметры -> ставим галочку для  пункта "*Отображать список операционных систем*" -> нажмите "*Ок*".

Comment: стоит, в списке операционных систем показывается тока винда

Comment: Какие операционные системы установлены на компьютере?